# Facebook Interest Graph Api always returning empty results

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a question regarding interests graph api that makes me pretty much confuse

```
/{user-id}/interests
```

I run it on graph tools but always getting an empty result and I'm aware that this method need an extended permission "user_interests"

How come that I always get the empty result and in which part of user facebook profile that can be said as user interest?

Answer (score 0):

This also depends on the security settings set by the "user-id", you will not be able to retrieve the list if "user-id" hasn't shared anything in public.

If he is a friend of yours then he should have shared interests with you.. else it will fetch empty.

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you are forming your query correctly? If you're doing it on Facebook itself then you're fine, but if you're using the API, the query would be along the lines of `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/{user-id}?fields=interests`.

To answer the other part of your question, interests is a deprecated field. There used to be a field on profiles that said "**Interests:**" but that has disappeared, and even though I still have one or two interests listed, I could not find a way to edit them. It is very possible that all your queries returned no result because there was no result to return.